# Creating pager for collection of anonymous type using PagedList.Mvc in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pagination, pagedlist

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC project. In my project I need to implement pagination feature. So I use PagedList.Mvc for it. I installed it running this command,"install-package PagedList.Mvc" in package manager console. I know how to implement pagination using it. But I am having a problem with implementing for collection of anonymous type view.

This is my action method implementing pagination logic

```
public ActionResult IpList(int page = 1)
        {
            List<IpVisitInfo> ipVisitList = new List<IpVisitInfo>();
            var rawVisits = trackTool.Visitors.GroupBy(x => x.IpAddress).Select(x => new { Visitors = x.Count(), IpAddress = x.Key, LastVisitedTime = x.OrderByDescending(c => c.Id).FirstOrDefault().VisitedAt }).ToPagedList(page,PageSize);
            if(rawVisits!=null && rawVisits.Count()>0)
            {
               foreach(var visit in rawVisits)
               {
                   IpVisitInfo info = new IpVisitInfo
                   {
                       IpAddress = visit.IpAddress,
                       LastVisitedAt = visit.LastVisitedTime,
                       TotalVisitors = visit.Visitors
                   };
                   ipVisitList.Add(info);
               }
            }
            IpVisitListVM model = new IpVisitListVM
            {
                IpList = ipVisitList
            };
            return View(model);
        }
```

As you can see I retrieved anonymous type collection and then loop through it and assign to strongly typed collection. I called to ToPagedList(PageNumber,PageSize) on anonymous type collection. But the problem is all the data required to implement pagination in view is in anonymous type collection. In view pagination has to be rendered something like this below.

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model.Items, page => Url.Action("List", new { page }))
```

This is my view model

```
 public class IpVisitListVM
    {
        public IEnumerable<IpVisitInfo> IpList { get; set; }
    }
```

So according to what I am doing, IpList of my view model does not have required data to render pagination. If I retrieve all anonymous collection fist without using ToPagedList() on it, then loop through each record, performance will be very slow, because it is retrieving all records first from database. I will have so many records. How can I use PagedList on anonymous typed view and pass to strongly typed view to implement pagination?

In view model I am using this property

```
IEnumerable<IpVisitInfo> IpList
```

Instead of this

```
IPagedList<IpVisitInfo> IpList
```

because it does not have enough data to create pagination. Because I filtered in action.

But if I can pass following as list

```
trackTool.Visitors.GroupBy(x => x.IpAddress).Select(x => new { Visitors = x.Count(), IpAddress = x.Key, LastVisitedTime = x.OrderByDescending(c => c.Id).FirstOrDefault().VisitedAt }).ToPagedList(page,PageSize);
```

pagination is perfectly created and performance will be better. Is there a way to pass that list?